# How to add value of two different binding variable like ${amount} and ${tax} in jquery ajax template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

I want to add two or more values of `variables`(which hold some value from XML file) inside `jquery Ajax template`.

I am trying to do like `${amount}+${tax}` then as result i am getting two number like 1000 + 140 instead of 1140.

```
<div class="netAmount"> <span onclick="dos(${callAmt})" class="${callAmt}">Net Fare
</span> <span onclick="dos(${callAmt})" class="${callAmt} hideFare">${amount} + ${tax}
</span> </div>
```

Please help to solve this stuff.

Any advice and help appreciable

Regards

Comment: Have you tried  `${amount+tax}`?

Comment: Do you have any code to share?

Comment: @Zakaria Acharki i tried , result was 1000140

Comment: <table id="Employee" class="table-hover alert-success">            <div class="netAmount">         
                         <span onclick="dos(${callAmt})"  class="${callAmt}">Net Fare</span>
                          <span onclick="dos(${callAmt})"  class="${callAmt} hideFare">${amount} + ${tax}</span>
            </div>         </table>                                   This is temple code , unable to add amount and tax values

Answer (score 2):

You should use `${amount+tax}` instead, if your variable are not integers you should parse them so you could use `${parseInt(amount)+parseInt(tax)}`.

Comment: You're welcome @Rakesh, Congratulations! You've Earned [vote-up privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) consider to use it.